# How to fix SQLAlchemy connection problem: 'Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format' when connecting to IBM db2 server hosted on IBM Cloud

Tags: python

So, I've been trying to connect to the IBM DB2 server hosted on IBM cloud for the past few days and managed to connect to it using the provided credentials and the 'ibm_db', 'ibm_db_sa', and the 'ibm_db_dbi' module. However, when I imported SQL magic and attempted to connect to the server, it failed.

I have tried a total of 3 methods: The IBM recommended method, and some other methods I found on the internet, which sadly, failed.

Method 1 (IBM recommended):

```py
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_sa
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
%load_ext sql

%sql ibm_db_sa://qcf54xxx:qz^d5stlkbr6lxxx@https://dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-03.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB
```

Error:

```py
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
Connection info needed in SQLAlchemy format, example:
               postgresql://username:password@hostname/dbname
               or an existing connection: dict_keys([])
```

Method 2:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('ibm_db_sa://qcf54xxx:qz^d5stlkbr6lxxx@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-03.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB')
```

Error:

```
Invalid Syntax
```

Method 3:

```py
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
import ibm_db_sa
db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://qcf54xxx:qz^d5stlkbr6lxxx@dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-03.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB')
metadata = MetaData()
```

Error:

```
Invalid Syntax
```

The method that succeeded (The method without SQLAlchemy)[Just for your references]:

```py
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_sa
import ibm_db_dbi
import pandas
#Connects to the IBM database
dsn_hostname = "dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-03.services.dal.bluemix.net" # e.g.: "dashdb-txn-sbox-yp-dal09-04.services.dal.bluemix.net"
dsn_uid = "qcf54xxx"        # e.g. "abc12345"
dsn_pwd = "qz^d5stlkbr6lxxx"      # e.g. "7dBZ3wWt9XN6$o0J"

dsn_driver = "{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}"
dsn_database = "BLUDB"            # e.g. "BLUDB"
dsn_port = "50000"                # e.g. "50000" 
dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"            # i.e. "TCPIP"

#DO NOT MODIFY THIS CELL. Just RUN it with Shift + Enter
#Create the dsn connection string
dsn = (
    "DRIVER={0};"
    "DATABASE={1};"
    "HOSTNAME={2};"
    "PORT={3};"
    "PROTOCOL={4};"
    "UID={5};"
    "PWD={6};").format(dsn_driver, dsn_database, dsn_hostname, dsn_port, dsn_protocol, dsn_uid, dsn_pwd)

#print the connection string to check correct values are specified
print(dsn)

#DO NOT MODIFY THIS CELL. Just RUN it with Shift + Enter
#Create database connection

try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
    print ("Connected to database: ", dsn_database, "as user: ", dsn_uid, "on host: ", dsn_hostname)

except:
    print ("Unable to connect: ", ibm_db.conn_errormsg() )
```

I expect to be able to use %sql to manipulate the database.

Thank you!

P.S. If I sounded rude or have offended you somehow, please understand that English is not my mother tongue. :(

Answer (score 0):

Using an existing python [library](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) for IBM DB2

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
import ibm_db_sa.ibm_db_sa

db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://user:password@host.name.com:50000/database')
db2.connect()
metadata = MetaData()

users = Table('STAFF', metadata, 
Column('ID', Integer, primary_key = True),
Column('NAME', String(9), nullable = False),
Column('DEPT', Integer, nullable = False),
Column('JOB', String(5), nullable = False)
)
metadata.create_all()
```

[Reference1](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0060891.html) , [Reference2](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/wiki/APIs#ibm_dbconnect)

Comment: here you are using user and password but I don't think I have any. What should be done?

Comment: I suggest u to setup a username and password. Anyhow use below conn string - 
Ibm_db_sa://host.name.com:50000/database

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but then did a pip install of ibm_db_sa and then made sure to import as above, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

installing the 1.3.9 version of sqlalchemy resolved the issue for me:

```
!pip install sqlalchemy==1.3.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to add `;security=SSL`:

```
... @hostname:port/bludb;security=SSL
```

to the **end of your connection string**.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried mine and this worked!

So, you are expected to use the same credentials you created in the previous course.

**Replace:**
%sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@my-hostname:my-port/my-db-name?security=SSL

**With:**
%sql ibm_db_sa://abc12345:7dBZ3wWt9XN6$o0J@54a2f15b-5c0f-46df-8954-7e38e612c2bd.c1ogj3sd0tgtu0lqde00.databases.appdomain.cloud:11112/BLUDB?security=SSL

The above is a **placeholder**, replace with your own generated service credentials.

Answer (score -1):

```
#try this;
%sql ibm_db_sa://my-username:my-password@my-hostname:my-port/my-db-name?security=SSL
```

#There could be something wrong with DB2, I am failing to long in also when the same code worked last time. 30/12/2021

Comment: You have just copied instructions from the IBM lab of Coursera which does not help solve the problem at all.